# In Node.js, an asynchronous recursive function is resolving empty promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm pulling information from an API that has the following response format:

```
{
  items: [{}, {}, {}],
  nextPage: {
    startIndex: 11
  }
}
```

so I wrote this program that checks if there's a `nextPage` property, and I make a subsequent request to the API with an offset = startIndex. Here's my code:

```
Serp.prototype.search = function(query, start, serps) {
  let deferred = this.q.defer();
  let url = '';
  if (start === 0) {
    url = `${GCS_BASE}/?key=${this.key}&cx=${this.cx}&q=${query}`;
  } else {
    url = `${GCS_BASE}/?key=${this.key}&cx=${this.cx}&q=${query}&start=${start}`;
  }

  this.https.get(url, (res) => {
    let rawData = '';

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      rawData += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
      let contactInfo = [];
      let result = JSON.parse(rawData);
      let totalResults = result.searchInformation.totalResults;

      // if total results are zero, return nothing.
      if (totalResults === 0) {
        serps.push(contactInfo);
        deferred.resolve(serps);
      // there's just one page of results.
      } else if (totalResults <= 10) {
        contactInfo = this._extractContactInfo(result.items, query.toLowerCase());
        serps.push(contactInfo);
        deferred.resolve(serps);
      // if there are more than 10, then page through the response.
      } else if ((totalResults > 10) && (result.queries.hasOwnProperty('nextPage'))) {
        // recursively and asynchronously pull 100 results.
        if (result.queries.nextPage[0].startIndex < 91) {
          contactInfo = this._extractContactInfo(result.items, query.toLowerCase());
          serps.push(contactInfo);
          this.search(query, result.queries.nextPage[0].startIndex, serps)
          .then(() => {
            deferred.resolve();
          });
        } else {
          contactInfo = this._extractContactInfo(result.items, query.toLowerCase());
          serps.push(contactInfo);
          let res = this.flatten(serps);
          deferred.resolve(res);
        }
      }
    });
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

That part of the code works just fine, the problem arises when I'm trying to call that `search` function I wrote this way:

```
  let promises = keywords.map((keyword) => {
    return Serps.search(keyword, startIndex, serps);
  });

  q.allSettled(promises)
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(results); // [ { state: 'fulfilled', value: undefined } ]
  }
```

My problem is that the promises are being fulfilled, but the value is undefined.

So what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by not returning an empty promise here:

```
  this.search(query, result.queries.nextPage[0].startIndex, serps)
  .then(() => {
      deferred.resolve(serps);
  });
```

I still need to flatten the results, so maybe there's a smarter solution, so far that works perfectly.